# Question about infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that a set $A$ is not finite if and only if there exist a set $B \subset A$ and a bijection between $B$ and a proper subset of $B$

My attempt: I can show that if a set is finite then there isn't a bijection between the set and a proper subset. That would be a answer for the backward pass of the Question by contrapositive, but I can't think of a proof for the forward one.

PS: In my book the definition of a infinite set is a set that cannot be bijected with $I_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ for any $n \in \mathbf{N}$

Comment: Isn't this the definition of infinite set?

Comment: In my book the definition of a infinite set is a set that cannot be bijected with $I_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ for any $n \in \mathbf{N}$

Comment: @Marco Usually, when a distinction is relevant, we call *Dedekind infinite* a set that is in bijection with a proper subset, and *finite* a set that is in bijection with an element of $\omega$ (and therefore *infinite* a set that is not in bijection with any element of $\omega$). In ZFC we have infinite if and only if Dedekind infinite, but not in ZF.

Comment: First show it for $\mathbb N$, then show that an infinite set has a countably infinite subset, and use these two in combination. (The latter fact is actually a weak form of the axiom of choice.)

Comment: In the title, did you mean *infinite* where you typed *infinity*?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The "infinite set has a countably infinite subset" proof was done in class, so it would be good for me to use that. Thank you, I had forgotten about it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you! Not my main language haha.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Take some element of it, call it $b_1$. $A\setminus\{b_1\}$ is not empty so take an element $b_2$ from it. Repeat this procedure, we get an infinite (countable) subset $B=\{b_1, b_2, …\}$ of $A$. (To be able to do this we must imply the axiom of choice, or at least the axiom of dependent choice.) Note that if $A\setminus\{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}$ would become empty at any step $n$ then $A$ would be equal to $\{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}.$ Since there is a bijection between $\{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}$ and $\{1,2,…,n\},$ it would make $A$ not infinite.

Now consider the following map from $B$ to $B$: $b_i \mapsto b_{i+1}, i=1,2,…$. It is clearly a bijection from $B$ to its proper subset $B\setminus \{b_1\}.$

Comment: FIne: but you should note that you are assuming a principle of set theory callled the principle of dependent choice.

Comment: Yes, but it works in ZFC.

Comment: Indeed, but we need to be careful about the assumptions we are making.

Comment: I think as a matter of pedagogy you also should be more explicit about how you know that $A \setminus \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n \} \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: @RobertShore Is the following reasoning good enough? If $A \setminus \{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}$ becomes empty at any step $n$ then $A$ equals to $\{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}$. Since there is a bijection between $\{b_1,b_2,…,b_n\}$ and $\{1,2,…,n\}$, $A$ is not infinite.

Comment: Yes, I think that's fine.  I suggest you edit your answer to include this argument.